# Javascript Function arguments as variables

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, arguments

Firstly i would like to note this is my first time using this site so if I do something incorrectly, i am sorry. Secondly i am intermediate at JavaScript but have only been truly been coding with for 3 days and am using it in an incremental game (more for myself to learn than others as there are quite a few out there). I've been doing pretty good and learning more as i go.

My problem is that I've gotten stuck using a function with arguments, my code looks like this:

```
<button onClick="getStorg(gargAmm,'gargAmm')"> Get Garage </button>Ammount: <span id="gargAmm">0<br />
```

Which is the HTML that launces the Function:

```
var gargAmm = 0;
function getStorg(buildAmm,buildID)
{
    buildAmm = buildAmm + 1;
    document.getElementById(buildID).innerHTML = buildAmm;
}
```

The display will make the "Amount:" go up to one when the button is first clicked, but then stalls. I've tried rearranging all sorts of variables and such but i just don't know why this doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Attach events in JavaScript, easier, less problems, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: I wonder, no offense, but how, in 2013, this stuff keeps creeping in? Is there a rogue tutorials site which only purpose is to seed anger and disinformation? *I mean aside from w3schools*...

Comment: it's good to know all ways. But only when you really do get to know all ways.

Comment: its because buildAmm doesn't exist after function is done/returns. And each time gets new value gargAmm which is never updated either in the fucntion.

Comment: Annnd you just got into closures lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is you're using the Global variable value

```
var gargAmm = 0;
```

Whenever you call the function it uses the same value as zero and increments it.
So your getting the value as 1 and its not incrementing further.
I have tried an another approach to solve your issue have a look at it.

```
   <button onClick="getStorg('gargAmm')">
        Get Garage 
   </button>Ammount: <span id="gargAmm">0</span><br />
```

Here is the javascript

```
    function getStorg(buildID)
    {
      var d= document.getElementById(buildID);
      var t= parseInt(d.innerText);
      t=t+1;
      document.getElementById(buildID).innerHTML = t;
    }
```

Here the text from the span is taken and converted to int and then incremented the value 
and inserted back into span.

Here is the Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p8E4G/

Comment: Yeah, not only does that work, but it cleans up my code alot. Like i said, im learning as i go do i did not know about parseInt(d.innerText); Thanks alot

Comment: @Ozay34 was this useful to you?

Comment: This was more than useful, it made my whole code much more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

**Simple:**

```
function myFunc(a,b) {
  b = b || 0;

  // b will be set either to b or to 0.
}
```